# A method to delete the elements in a linkedlist using C

Tags: c, linked-list

So I'm asked to make a method that empty out the entire linked list.

This is what I have now, and I have no idea why it doesn't want to work:

```
void deleteList(){



    }
```

Comment: But `current` can only be NULL in your function

Comment: `current` is not assigned to anything.  Who knows what `while (current != NULL)` will do?  Certainly `deleteList()` should be something like `deleteList(struct node *head)` or `deleteList(struct node **head)` along with other code changes.

Comment: Yeah. 'void deleteList()' - what list?

Comment: The signature is wrong: `void deleteList(void)` Also, this is a _function_, not a _method_. C does not support methods. Please use correct phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs to be passed the head of the list, i.e. `struct node *head` that it can operate on.  Then you can use that instead of `current` to keep track of the current head.

```
void deleteList(struct node *head){

    struct node* next;

    while (head!= NULL) {
        next = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}
```

Edit:

Since the list head is a global variable, then you would do this:

```
struct node *head;   // Initialized elsewhere

void deleteList(){

    struct node* current = head;
    struct node* next;

    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I thought first, but the method was given without the passing anything in the parameter: it was only like this:  

'void deleteList(){

 }'

Comment: @TalalAlsarrani So is the list in question stored in a global variable?  If so, you should use that as your `current`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function never assigns "current" to any node to begin with.  Because of this your while loop never runs because "current" effectively always equals NULL (**hopefully**, actually it is undefined and could cause very strange behavior).  The loop is always skipped.  Try passing the first node of the list into your function as a parameter:

```c
void deleteList(struct node * start) {

    //"start" points to the first node in the list, point "current" at it
    struct node * current = start;
    struct node * next;

    while (current != NULL) {
       next = current->next;
       //what's this pop doing?  It seems unnecessary to the logic here
       pop(next);
       //free "current" and then point "current" at "next"
       free(current); 
       current = next;
    }
}
```

This would also allow you to release an arbitrary segment of the end of the list by providing "start" the node you want to begin releasing at.  It need not be the very first node.

Comment: That is what I thought first, but the method was given without the passing anything in the parameter: it was only like this:  

void deleteList(){

 }

Comment: That would seem to suggest that your list is some kind of globally scoped variable.  Assuming your list variable is called my_list, and it contains a pointer to the first node called first_node, you might write:  struct node * current = my_list->first_node instead of passing in the parameter.